# Runtime Events in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to display a control such as textbox by pressing a button.
Meanwhile I want to hide or permanently close that control by clicking another button.
I tried by can't access that control outside the method where its created.

Is there any way to solve.

Comment: Declare the control globally, then so that you can access them in all the needed method.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information

Answer (score 1):

Put the control into a variable that is available in a larger scope, for example a class variable.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt for your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

If you give the control a unique name when you create it:

```
var myTextbox = new TextBox { Name = "uniqueName", Visible = true };
```

You could find it later using:

```
var myGeneratedControl = Controls.Find("uniqueName", true).SingleOrDefault();

if (myGeneratedControl != null)
    myGeneratedControl.Hide();
```

Comment: I am beginner so I need a simple code please describe in full code with an example

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             TextBox TextBox1=new TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
            TextBox1.Location = new Point(375, 150);
            TextBox1.Size=new Size(100,20);
            TextBox1.Name = "TB1";
            TextBox1.Text = "TEXT BOX";
           
         
        }
    }

Comment: Another question is that I need to add border radius property to a textbox I tried in ASP.NET but I couldn't make it work in Windows Forms